# DateTime format conversion in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert datetime of different formats (`MM/dd/yyyy`, `dd/MM/yyyy`, `yyyy-MM-dd` etc) to `yyyy-mm-dd` using Datetime.TryParse().
The conversion is successful if the date time format supplied is `yyyy-mm-dd` or `MM/dd/yyyy`.
However when the format is `dd/MM/yyyy` the month and the date are interchanged.
My code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable DtTable = new DataTable();
                DtTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
                Console.WriteLine("Date Values");
                string[] DateString=new string[7];
                DateString[0] = "2015-08-07 12:12:00";
                DateString[1] = "08/07/2015 12:12:00";
                DateString[2] = "07/08/2015 12:12:00";
                DateString[3] = "8/7/2015 12:12:00";
                DateString[4] = "7/08/2015 12:12:00";
                DateString[5] = "2015/08/7 12:12:00";
                DateString[6] = "2015/08/07";
                foreach(string date in DateString)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(date);
                    DateTime DtTemp=new DateTime();
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(date,CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None, out DtTemp))
                    {
                        DtTable.Rows.Add(DtTemp);
                    }                
                }
                Console.WriteLine("-----output--------------");
                foreach (DataRow drrow in DtTable.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(drrow[0]`.`ToString());
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "However when the format is dd/MM/yyyy the month and the date are interchanged." Well yes - given *only* a string of "06/03/2015" is that March 6th or June 3rd? You list both `dd/MM/yyyy` and `MM/dd/yyyy` as possible formats, so how do you expect to tell the difference between them, other than when the day is more than 12?

Comment: Well, you're telling me to look at that date in the `en-US` culture. So to me, "06/03/2015" is and will always be June 3rd, 2015. And don't try to convince me otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

Try [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w2sa9yss(v=VS.110).aspx) method:

```
string dateString = "20/10/2014";
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have *three* formats:

```
  MM/dd/yyyy 
  dd/MM/yyyy 
  yyyy-MM-dd
```

but as you can see `MM/dd/yyyy` and `dd/MM/yyyy` are *overlaping*, i.e.

```
  01/02/2015
```

is it *1st of Feb* or *2nd of Jan*? If in order to resolve the *ambiguity* 
you agree to *change* the formats slightly, e.g.

```
  MM/dd/yyyy 
  dd.MM.yyyy // note dots
  yyyy-MM-dd
```

you can implement the routine like that:

```
public static Boolean TryParseExtended(String value, out DateTime result) {
  result = DateTime.MinValue;

  String[] formatsToTry = new String[] {
    "MM/dd/yyyy",
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
    "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss",
    "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss",
  };

  foreach (var format in formatsToTry)
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result)
      return true;

  return false;
}
```

...

```
  foreach (string date in DateString) {
    Console.WriteLine(date);
    DateTime DtTemp = new DateTime();

    if (TryParseExtended(date, out DtTemp)) {
      ....
    } 
  }
```